# Using The Terminal Command and Emacs To Play The Video Game "Tetris"?

Tags: macos, terminal, games, emacs

OS X via the Terminal command and [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) apparently allows you to access and play a version of the video game [Tetris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris).

How do you accomplish this (and can you play via keyboard controls) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start emacs just type emacs<kbd>↩</kbd>
This tells the shell to look for an executable file emacs in a directory listed in the PATH environment variable.

When in emacs run the command tetris that is <kbd>esc</kbd>xtetris

The controls are the arrow keys

Note that something seems to be wrong with the score file e.g. it won't save high scores etc.